# What is the difference between engine.begin() and engine.connect()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, transactions, commit

i go first straight for my questions: Why would one rather use `engine.connect()` instead of `engine.begin()`, if the second is more reliable? Then, why is it still on the tutorial page of SQLAlchemy and everywhere in stackoverflow? Performance?

Why does `engine.connect()` work so inconsistently? Is the problem withing the autocommit?

My backgroundstory to this is, that i just resolved an issue. Normal SQL-queries like `SELECT`, `CREATE TABLE` and `DELETE` would work flawlessly when using `engine.connect()`. Though, using `MERGE` would work very inconsistently. Sometimes committing, sometimes blocking other queries, sometimes nothing. [Here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5405) it is recommended to use `engine.begin()` for `MERGE` queries.

So i substituted the following code:

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute('MERGE Table1 USING Table2 ON .....')
```

by

```
with engine.begin() as connection:
    connection.execute('MERGE Table1 USING Table2 ON .....')
```

and now everything works perfectly. Inlcuding the queries of `SELECT`,`CREATE TABLE` and `DELETE`.
In the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=commit#sqlalchemy.engine.Transaction.commit) it says the second option uses transactions with a transaction-commit, but the scope of `with engine.connect()` does an autocommit aswell. Sorry i am a complete newbie to SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> the scope of with engine.connect() does an autocommit as well

No, it doesn't. That's the most striking difference between `with engine.connect()` and `with engine.begin()`

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    # do stuff
# on exit, the transaction is automatically rolled back

with engine.begin() as conn:
    # do stuff
# on exit, the transaction is automatically committed if no errors occurred
```

As [mentioned in the tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#committing-changes), `engine.connect()` is used with the "[explicitly] commit as you go" style of code, while `engine.begin()` represents the "begin once" style.

Transactions are used in both cases. However, `engine.begin()` begins the transaction immediately, while `engine.connect()` waits until a statement is executed before beginning the transaction. That permits us to alter the characteristics of the transaction that will eventually be started. A common use of this `engine.connect()` feature is to use non-default transaction isolation:

```py
# default isolation level
with engine.connect() as conn:
    print(conn.get_isolation_level())  # REPEATABLE READ

# using another isolation level
with engine.connect().execution_options(
    isolation_level="SERIALIZABLE"
) as conn:
    print(conn.get_isolation_level())  # SERIALIZABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! But [this tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html) says that `engine.connection()` by default autocommits on `connection.execute(query)` **IF** the query contains specific SQL commandas like `INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE`. In my case it did not commit as i used MERGE :P

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#library-level-e-g-emulated-autocommit)? If so, that's deprecated in 1.4 and will go away in 2.0.

Comment: Exactly! But it is still active in 1.4. As the anaconda repository still holds version 1.4, i think many will still encounter this issue.