# SQLAlchemy: select ... into having no effect

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Is `select ... into` not something we're able to do in SQLAlchemy?

The following is a minimal example of something I'm trying to do - and it isn't adding a table to my d/b as expected.

```
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
server = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
database = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
authentication = 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
username = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

conn = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    'DRIVER=' + driver +
    ';SERVER=' + server +
    ';DATABASE=' + database +
    ';UID=' + username +
    ';AUTHENTICATION=' + authentication + ';'
)

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(conn))

with engine.connect() as cx:
    cx.execute(text('''
        select
            name
        into testing.test
        from core.person
    '''))
```

It's failing silently - I'm not getting any error message. And other queries that I run are executing fine.

Are we not able to do `select ... into` queries using `text` in this way? If not, is there an alternative besides separate `create table` and `insert into` statements?

Comment: The problem may be that you didn't commit the transaction.

Comment: Try using `with engine.begin() as cx:` instead of `with engine.connect() as cx:`

Comment: Thanks both, that seems like it was the issue. @GordThompson I'll accept it if you want to post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

@GordThompson's suggestion fixed this for me, swapping `engine.connect()` for `engine.begin()`:

```
with engine.begin() as cx:
    cx.execute(text('''
        select
            name
        into testing.test
        from core.person
    '''))
```

The commit behaviour of the two functions differs, as described in more detail by Gord [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72716632/4659442).